# how to compile lighttpd modules statically

Tags: c, lighttpd, autoconf, automake, libtool

I have currently complied lighttpd from source

```
./configure --prefix=/home/lighttpd \
--without-pcre \
--without-zlib \
--without-bzip2
```

I also tried -enable-static --disable-shared option, but modules still loading from lib directory

I want to compile all lighttpd module in single binary instead of loading from lib directory, how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross-posted to https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/3/topics/6615

Lighttpd can be built statically using SCons or using make.  Briefly:

SCons:
$ scons -j 4 build_static=1 build_dynamic=0 prefix=/custom/inst/path install

make:

# edit src/Makefile.am and in the section under 'if LIGHTTPD_STATIC', update lighttpd_SOURCES with each module to be included in the static build or just use the entire list that is already there

$ LIGHTTPD_STATIC=yes ./configure -C --enable-static=yes
$ make

More details in https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/3/topics/5912

[edit] To build statically using 'make', use lighttpd git master branch or lighttpd 1.4.40+

Comment: It seems that the maintainers have added a fullstatic target for scons, so replacing `build_static` with `build_fullstatic` should produce the desired output. This applies to lighttpd version `1.4.64` at least.

Comment: @swalog FYI build_fullstatic was add some 17 years ago in lighttpd 1.4.11 (https://git.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/lighttpd1.4/commit/5da3530140fbccd34ab49309cdd9106893f19ac8) and is documented in the [INSTALL](https://git.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/lighttpd1.4/src/branch/master/INSTALL) file

Comment: I see. Apologies if I'm off by a decade or two :D. However, when compiling using `build_static`, the output binary was indeed still dynamically linked. And given the OP question for a standalone binary, only the `build_fullstatic` option produced what I understood to be the desired output.

Comment: Compiling on alpine using scons, the output of `ldd sconsbuild/static/build/lighttpd`:
`/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f38d35cb000)` (and some other libs). While `ldd sconsbuild/fullstatic/build/lighttpd` (the output target when using `build_fullstatic`, is as expected reported as `"Not a valid dynamic program"`

Comment: "And given the OP question for a standalone binary"  I disgaree, and so did OP since my answer was accepted.  OP's question was "how to compile lighttpd modules statically" and posted "I want to compile all lighttpd module in single binary instead of loading from lib directory".  In any case, both `build_static` and `build_fullstatic` options are available and documented in the [INSTALL](https://git.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/lighttpd1.4/src/branch/master/INSTALL) file.

Answer (score 0):

Compile it with flag -DLIGHTTPD_STATIC. If gcc will warn you about syntax,  force interpret gcc as the C99 standard:

```
make CFLAGS=-DLIGHTTPD_STATIC -std=c99
```

Also you must change src/Makefile.in which is generated by configure to add the modules you want to include. Specifically, add to am__liblightcomp_la_SOURCE_DIST, am__lighttpd_SOURCES_DIST and common_src:

```
mod_access.c mod_staticfile.c
```

And also add the objects.
To am__objects_1 and am__objects_2

```
mod_access.$(OBJEXT) mod_staticfile.$(OBJEXT)
```

if src/plugin-static.h file is not available, change src/plugin.c file, find line #include "plugin-static.h", coment it and add this below:

```
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_access)
PLUGIN_INIT(mod_staticfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `lighttpd` explains that using `build_static` will only cause it to be statically linked with its own modules (`mod_*.so` files). It will still dynamically link external dependencies (those in `/lib*/*`).

If you were not mixing these up, regarding your experience of:

> I also tried -enable-static --disable-shared option, but modules still loading from lib directory

And all you wanted was for these modules to be statically included in the `lighttpd` binary, then the other answers should be correct and valid.

However, if you want to have a single binary, so that there are no externally dynamic dependencies. Then you need to use both `scons` and  replace `build_static=1` with `build_fullstatic=1`. The `Makefile` setup doesn't have this option.

---

#### `build_static=1`

```
scons -j 4 build_static=1 build_dynamic=0
```

Using `ldd` to show which dynamic libraries it needs:

```
ldd sconsbuild/static/build/lighttpd
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff0478f000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f760191e000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f76018e4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f76016bc000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7601a5a000)
```

**PS:** if you built a shared version, the `mod_*.so` files would still not show up here, as those are lazily loaded from within the execution of `lighttpd`, based on your config file.

---

#### `build_fullstatic=1`

```
scons -j 4 build_fullstatic=1 build_dynamic=0
```

```
ldd sconsbuild/fullstatic/build/lighttpd
    not a dynamic executable
```

Which is what I assume you wanted to see.

Comment: The contents of your post is already documented in the lighttpd documentation [INSTALL](https://git.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/lighttpd1.4/src/branch/master/INSTALL), which is one of the first places people should look when building from source.

Comment: Just trying to be helpful here. It's not immediately apparent what things are baked as part of the static libraries for which build options. Though, I do agree that it shouldn't be an issue if one read and understood the documentation well. However, setting that bar would invalidate 99% of the contents on SO. You also did point this out repeatedly in the discussion earlier. So, I'm not entirely sure what wish to contribute by bringing it up again, as the first sentence in the above answer starts with "The documentation of lighttpd explains ...". Perhaps you could clarify.

Comment: "The documentation of lighttpd" is extremely vague.  You could have linked more directly to the specific documentation (cite your references!), which is what I did in my comment above linking to the lighttpd [INSTALL](https://git.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/lighttpd1.4/src/branch/master/INSTALL) file.